# how to use wildcards in seacrh in ScrewTurn Wiki

Tags: screwturn

I have ScrewTurn Wiki version 3.0.5.600. 
When we try to use searching like 'projec*' there are not results. 
But if we try search word 'project' there are a lot of results.

What is problem here? How can i fix it?

Comment: Can somedoby help me?

Comment: I don't believe Screwturn 3.x has any wildcard/partial word support.  Search is by a single or multiple word hit(s).